# Ubuntu 19.04 nodejs and npm wont run show Aborted (core dump)

Tags: nodejs, npm, segmentation-fault

I installed nodejs and npm freshly after a removal via

```
apt install nodejs
apt install npm
```

but if I put

```
npm -v
```

I get an Abort error and core dump

```
 1: 0x948a70 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x997982 node::options_parser::GetOptions(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [node]
 3: 0xba5e0a  [node]
 4: 0xba69b9 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 5: 0x99aae14fc5d
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've updated upgraded rebooted etc. it simply does not work.

```
node --version
```

has a segmentation fault

```
v11.8.0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I uninstalled npm after using it's 'n' to install node 11.8 and somehow that seems to being starting, so something is wrong with the dependencies for npm I guess?

Comment: You should remove them and try using their method of installation ( https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall ). If it still fails open a bug report, and give them the dump.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of conflicting npm versions of Node and Node.js. You can try removing Node.js by using the following commands:

`sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

After that you need to run the autoremove command to remove any leftover dependencies that are no longer needed:

`sudo apt autoremove`

Running these commands should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I added an amendment and now see a comment hinting at the cause let me clarify my error.
This is really messed up.

If you run node you get the version
'which nodejs' points to in /usr/bin/nodejs
but if you ask
'which node' you get /usr/local/bin/node

This confusion is likely why npm fails because it's using the wrong version of node.

Out of the box apt list nodejs shows nodejs/disco 10.15.2~dfsg-1 amd64 while which node or which nodejs and calling it all come up with missing not found.

after apt install npm I get these results
which npm = /usr/bin/npm

npm -v = 5.8.0

which node = /usr/bin/node

which nodejs = /usr/bin/nodejs

node --version = v10.15.2

nodejs --version = v10.15.2

Next I install 'n' via npm install -g n and follow through adding n 11.8.0 the only version still working properly for me.

still all nodes point to 10.15.2 but it's installed into /usr/local/n/versions/node/11.8.0

that has in it's bin the node and a link to npm

npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

so 'n' is not installing the version properly.

I think I'll end up getting (my node version of choice aka last that actually works) node-v11.8.0-linux-x64 manually from nodejs download link and build a proper installer [copy it over and link it up]. It's just I use this for developing as well and it was handy to have npm and 'n' but it's not working so?